# Android: Transparent dialog activity in API 8

Tags: android, dialog, android-activity

I have problem...

I'm trying to show Activity as a Dialog.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, CityOnMapDialog.class);
intent.putExtra("city",cityString);
startActivity(intent);
```

And I have declared it in **Manifest** as:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.myapp.dialogs.CityOnMapDialog" 
          android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" 
          android:windowIsTranslucent="false">
</activity>
```

Please can someone tell me **WHY** this dialog shows up **transparent** in API **8** ?

Comment: I think it's because of the theme... `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"`. How does it show on higher API levels?

Comment: I have higher API and it is normal, non transparent... do you think that
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FF000000")));
Can help ? (For black color on background)

Comment: `#ff000000` is full opaque black. Try it, it sounds promising. But - the theme is still the OLDE API 8 style one, which could force the apha anyway.

Comment: If you included the support library into your project, you might try: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dark.Dialog"`

Comment: Can you post me link here for the support library ? please ?

Comment: No, you just **right-click** the project name and choose **Android Tools/Add Support Library**. That's it. Provideed that your SDK is up to date